# CiviHR extensions

Tags: civihr

We just installed CiviHR 1.4. Although the tabs for *absences* and *jobs* are showing, there is no way of adding any information.

We have disabled, enabled and refreshed these extensions to no avail.

All the other extensions seem to be working OK.

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Dave. hi. obvious question perhaps but you haven't indicated your version of civi. also if i read it right https://civicrm.org/extensions/civihr says 1.4 is sandbox. is that right? might help others help you to flesh out your question with such information

Answer (score 1):

Will add as an answer in case it helps. According to the [documentation](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civihr) 1.4 is pre-release ie sandbox and is [not compatible with 4.6](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36518.0).

> From the development team at Compucorp:
>   The MVP product (for 1.4) to be released at the end of the year (2015) will be based on Civi4.7. At the moment we support v4.5 and will probably continue to do so until the MVP.

Comment: I think you have probably answered the question. The version of civi that this is installed on is 4.6.8. I'll go back to civihr 1.3 and see if that resolves the issues. I'll put the result back up for information. Thanks.